# Block all connections but allow only a few ports with iptables

Tags: iptables

I need rules that :

1. Block all incoming traffic ( internet > server) but allow outgoing ( server > internet ) and allow local services to run too
2. Only accept incoming traffic from ports I want.

I also need to this while in a ssh session ( I've been locked before ).

The reason I'm asking is because I'm unable to use UFW with my VPS provider... apparently because their kernel / OpenVZ...

While I tried to learn the commands by myself that is like learning to use a tool and trying to build a house. And would be really nice if I could have some productivity today instead of spending hours and hours trying to fix this. If someone could help me I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First allow your specific port then block all incoming traffice

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

where 22 your demo port change it on your demand

Block all incoming traffic

```
# iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

Allow all outgoing packet

```
# iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: You should also include the `ip6tables` commands, as `iptables` won't apply rules for IPv6, and half of your firewall will be wide open.

Comment: I'm getting iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name. I wish I could just change my vps provider but i already paid for 3 months :/

Comment: also how can I accept tcp and udp on the port I selected? do i need to add 2 rules?

Comment: yes . After this rules iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT you add another rules for udp packet iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

Comment: I tried this but it wont allow reply from the outside. I can't use apt-get for example

Answer (score 2):

@Rakib provided a great answer, and I think it should be the accepted one. The answer I am giving just adds onto his. I recommend making a shell script so that you can have it run automatically when the OS is booted, or on demand without having to type it all out again:

```
#!/bin/sh

IPT = iptables

#allowing the specific port
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

#block all incoming traffic
$IPT -A INPUT -j REJECT

#ALLOW ALL OUTGOING PACKETS
$IPT -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#same thing for ip6tables (IPv6)
IPT = ip6tables
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -j REJECT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Also the script was done twice, with the only difference being that **ip6tables** was included, so that the apply for IPv6 as well, as @Michael Mol said in his comment under @Rakib's answer