# How to block all except specific ports with firewall-cmd

Tags: centos, iptables, firewalld

I'm using CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core).

I want to block incoming and outgoing connections from all the TCP/UDP ports except a few ones.

Following is the current firewall configuration of the OS:

```
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
  interfaces: ens160

# firewall-cmd --list-ports
5901/tcp 5902/tcp 5912/tcp 5911/tcp 5913/tcp 5914/tcp

# firewall-cmd --list-services
dhcpv6-client ssh
```

Although firewall only seems to allow connections over the ports listed above, I can still use certain ports such as 22 (SSH), 80 (HTTP), etc.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `firewall-cmd --list-services`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've updated my post with the output of `firewall-cmd --list-services`.

Comment: Last time I checked firewall-cmd cannot block outgoing connections and I'm not sure about *I can still use certain ports such as 22 (SSH), 80 (HTTP), etc.* - if you're connecting locally, i.e. to 127.0.0.1, all the ports will be open.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I can connect via SSH from another machine in my local area network.

Comment: You have the ssh port open as indicated by --list-services.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov What about port 80 (HTTP)? Although it should be blocked, I can establish connections via port 80.

Comment: Establish connections from where?

Comment: From the machine itself to a website.

Comment: What's the `machine`, what's the `website`? Are they on the same network? Where are you setting up your firewall? You provide very little info and expect us to be clairvoyant. Also, you're dabbling with firewalling while seemingly understanding very little about TCP/IP, UDP, ICMP and networking in general. By chance you might actually set up the firewall the way you want but that's not how I'd approach the issue.

Comment: I said the machine `itself`, so the machine I want to block connections. The website is `a` website, that means it can be google.com, duckduckgo.com, etc.

Comment: Hopefully someone else will help you. You've got a mess of a question and I'm not sure you truly understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I think I clearly stated my problem. I am neither Linux nor networking expert and I am trying to find an answer to my problem. Thanks anyways for your help.

Comment: Perhaps using `iptables` directly is the best way forward for you but that will require a good understanding of networking.

Answer (score 1):

There you can find the answer with iptables

https://superuser.com/questions/769814/how-to-block-all-ports-except-80-443-with-iptables/770191

you can just put the ports you need open there intead of 80 and 443

Comment: I tried to apply a similar solution that was mentioned at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358701 but it didn't help.

Comment: There is a chain called `IN_public_allow` in the firewall rules that are listed by iptables. Is it something related to public zone that is listed by firewall-cmd?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the /etc/firewalld/zones directory and change public.xml

Default /etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <service name="dhcpv6-client"/>
  <service name="cockpit"/>
</zone>
```

Then

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

You can change your zone from public to drop.

```
cp /usr/lib/firewalld/zones/drop.xml /etc/firewalld/zones/
 
#Add to /etc/firewalld/zones/ the following to permit ssh.
<service name="ssh"/>
 
firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=drop
firewall-cmd --reload
```

If you elect to change default firewall zone to DROP, you may have to add readd your ports to it.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port={5901,5902,5912.5911,5913,59124}/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```